# Python 2.7 - Can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

My code:

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
nr=85365
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password})
nrs = urllib.urlencode({'id' : nr})
opener.open('http://ddddd/takelogin.php', login_data)
while True:
    resp = opener.open('http://ddd/userdetails.php?id=' + str(nr))
    s=resp.read()
    ss=re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",s)
    file = open("cookies.txt","a")
    file.write(ss +"\n")
    #time.sleep(10)
    print nr
    nr+=1
```

i want to save  email from output.
i have this error, i use python 2.7

```
    file.write(ss +"\n")
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: `ss` as the result of `re.findall()` is obviously a list. what did you expect? also, your regex is woefully inadequate.

Comment: And how can I transform it?

Comment: what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting one email per line, you need this

```
with open("cookies.txt","a") as file:
    while True:
        resp = opener.open('http://ddd/userdetails.php?id=' + str(nr))
        s=resp.read()
        ss=re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",s)
        for email in ss:
            file.write(email +"\n")
        #time.sleep(10)
        print nr
        nr+=1
```

I would suggest you limit the value of `nr` to avoid the infinite loop